# How do I attach and update an existing entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to construct a disconnected object on my web page:

```
var entity = new MyEntity();
entity.ID = IdFromPage;
entity.Name = UpdatedNameFromPage;
```

Connect it to my object context and then call context.Save()

but how do I do this? I dont want to have to use linq to extract the entity like this...

```
var entityFromPage = new MyEntity();
entity.ID = IdFromPage;
entity.Name = UpdatedNameFromPage;

var connectedEntity = _db.MyEntities.Where(x => x.ID == IdFromPage).First();
connectedEntity.ID = entityFromPage.ID;
connectedEntity.Name = entityFromPage.Name;
```

Because the second part of this script may be massive and I dont want to have to re-map everything. I just want to slot it in on the ID and then  call Save() is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to.

If you know it already exists on the database,

```
objectcontext.YourEntities.Attach(entity);
objectcontext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(entity, EntityState.Modified);       
objectcontext.SaveChanges();
```

(If it's a new entity, then you add it to the context)

Comment: At least you have to set the entity state to `Modified`, otherwise your code has no effect.